# How can I change a WebBrowser object dynamically in a running Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm building an app that preloads webpages when it's run. Then, if the user does some actions (e.g. clicking a button) the program shows in a panel the preloaded webpage.

In order to achieve this, I have defined a `WebBrowser` object in the `Form`. This `WebBrowser` is called `webBrowser1`. In the constructor of the `Form` I create one `WebBrowser` object per button (`wb1`, `wb2` and `wb3`). Then, I use the method `Navigate` on each of the objects to preload the webpages. In the onClick handlers, I reassign `webBrowser1` to one of the objects created in the constructor.

The problem is that I can't visualize the `WebBrowser` after the reassignment.

This is the class that implements the Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private WebBrowser wb1;
    private WebBrowser wb2;
    private WebBrowser wb3;

    public Form1()
    {
        wb1 = new WebBrowser();
        wb1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
        wb2 = new WebBrowser();
        wb2.Navigate("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        wb3 = new WebBrowser();
        wb3.Navigate("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1 = wb1;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1 = wb2;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1 = wb3;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1:** What do I mean by "preload" the webpages?

I don't know the exact technical term to describe this, but the effect I'm looking for is equivalent to the tabs in a web browser. For example, let's say that I'm browsing the web with Mozilla Firefox and I have three tabs open. The first tab has the Google homepage loaded, the second one has the stackoverflow homepage and the third one Wikipedia. When I switch tabs there isn't a reloading of the webpage (not even from cache), it just brings whichever webpage is loaded in the tab to the foreground.

Comment: `webBrowser1.Navigate(webBrowser2.Url);`. It will load the WebSite resources from the cache.

Comment: Also, move the initialization of your WebBrowsers after `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: `webBrowser1 = wb1;`  Just assigns the `wb1` to `webBrowser1` variable. But still previous browser object which you had in `webBrowser1` and still exists in the `Controls` collection of the form, will be shown on the form. You just changed the address which `webBrowser1` variable is pointing to a non-visible web browser control which is not member of controls collection of the form.

Comment: @Jimi I thought of that option, but the problem is that I can't keep the webpages preloaded.

Comment: @reza-aghaei This seems to be in the right direction. How do I make the new `WebBrowser` visible and the old one invisible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with *I can't keep the webpages preloaded*. Preloading means storing the resources of a site/page in cache.  The WebBrowser already does that. Rendering the page inside the control is another matter. When you navigate to that address again, the resources will be loaded from the cache. If this is not enough, you should add a more detailed description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: You could take a different path: paint the current website's loaded page to a PictureBox while an invisible WebBrowser navigates to different URLs. You can define the ClientSize of the WebBrowser and use `Control.DrawToBitmap()` to take a shot of the current Page in the `DocumentCompleted` event (it doesn't matter if the WB is invisible). It takes some checking on the loading of IFrames, but it's quite simple. Then just click on the preview image to load the related page from cache in the visible WebBrowser.

Comment: @Jimi Sorry for the confusion. I've edited the question providing more details regarding the desired behaviour of the application.

Comment: In that case, tha Page has already been rendered. You just need to add the hidden WebBrowser control to `this.Controls` (after you have definined its Size and Location), then show it. It will present its rendered DC without reloading the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the question comments I have to manage the `Controls` collection of the form. I also copied some of the code generated by visual studio in the constructor to make all the `WebBrowser` objects have the same display features. I'm not sure if this last point is necessary.

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private WebBrowser wb1;
    private WebBrowser wb2;
    private WebBrowser wb3;

    public Form1()
    {
        wb1 = new WebBrowser();
        wb1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
        wb2 = new WebBrowser();
        wb2.Navigate("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        wb3 = new WebBrowser();
        wb3.Navigate("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
        List<WebBrowser> lwb = new List<WebBrowser>();
        lwb.Add(wb1);
        lwb.Add(wb2);
        lwb.Add(wb3);
        foreach (WebBrowser wb in lwb)
        {
            wb.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            wb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            wb.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            wb.Name = "webBrowser1";
            wb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 208);
            wb.TabIndex = 0;
        }
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bringToFront(WebBrowser wb)
    {
        this.panel1.Controls.Remove(this.webBrowser1);
        this.webBrowser1 = wb;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bringToFront(wb1);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bringToFront(wb2);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bringToFront(wb3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create all web browsers, set them all to be invisible and dock = fill. Add them all to panel1. When you want to bring one of them to front, just make it visible and bring it to front then make rest of them invisible.